# Receive ClassNotFoundException when using JRE Deployment Rule Set

Tags: java, deployment, set, classnotfoundexception, rule

Receive ClassNotFoundException when using JRE Deployment Rule Set
Platform: Windows 7 x64
Browser: IE 11 32-bit and 64-bit
Installed JRE versions:
1.8.0_60 32-bit & 64-bit
1.7.0_79 32-bit & 64-bit

JRE Deployment Rule Set (DRS) is signed and is valid. I added force and changed the DRS version from 1.0 to 1.1, it didn’t change anything.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ruleset version="1.1+">
  <rule>
    <id location="http://%Site%:%Port%/%blahblahblah%/" />
    <action permission="run" version="1.7.0_79" force="true" />
   </rule>
</ruleset>
```

I have a site with two different Java applets that are available through different links. The applets are from an external vendor and have not been updated, thus the need for this function in the DRS. Both the applets launch Java and then switch to JRE 1.7.0_79, as directed. One loads fine, the other errors with ClassNotFoundException – com/%AppName%/wcm/api/User. The details in the Java Console lead with, "log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (%AppName%.vw.base).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly."

The kicker is that when only JRE 1.7.0_79 is installed both applets load without issue.

My best guess is that the DRS can’t handle spaces in some of the paths. I’ve seen this line “com/%AppName%/wcm/api/User“ as the trailing part of a longer path in the logs. Ultimately I’d love to go to the vendor and tell them to fix their code, but I’m doing this because that hasn’t happened yet. :P

Has anyone seen this before or does anyone have any idea what the resolution to the issue might be?

Comment: Now I see if the application has been cached in a previous version and before employing the DRS it will work. If the cache is cleared you're out of luck. Of course the cache doesn't appear to be something that can be moved from one device\profile to another. 

I may need to find a way to force the application to cache.

Comment: It's starting to look like the issue stems from a couple unregistered or unsigned jar files on the server. It doesn't appear to be an issue with the DRS. No client side settings seem to resolve this issue. I reference saying not allowing applications to cache solves the issue, this doesn't work in this case. 

The solution will ultimately be getting the server side admin to register or sign the files in question.